# VBA Copy/Paste a Range in Next Available Column Then Add a Single Day to One of the Newly Pasted Cells Repeatedly

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to create a button with an attached macro that will copy a range with formulas and data, then paste it to the next available column, and finally add one day to one specific cell. The problem I'm having is that I want to do it over and over, with the each new pasted cell adding one date from the previously pasted one. The idea is that I click the button, it pastes the orginal range plus one day added to that specific cell, then I can add data to that new pasted block, then click the button and get a new pasted block with the next specific cell having one day added to it.

So far I have this:

```
Sub PasteToNextEmptyColumn()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        
    Range("A4:C14").Copy
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths
    ActiveSheet.Cells(4, Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Offset(0, 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteAll

    Range("E9").Value = DateAdd("d", 1, (Range("E9")))


    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Post an example of your starting data, what you want to happen, and what is actually happening.  Use either a [Mark down table](https://www.tablesgenerator.com/markdown_tables) or use a sample [Sample Spreadsheet Maker](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/e/1FAIpQLSeprZS3Al0n7JiVQIEiCi_Ad9FRXbpgB7x1-Wq6iAfdmVbWiA/viewform) to illustrate.

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little unsure on what you're trying to accomplish, but if this helps.

With a date you can treat it like a value and just put:

- Range("E9") = Range("E9") + 1 ' this will input the date in the same cell E9

Maybe ensure the date is inn DD/MM/YYYY or another recognised format.

It seems as though the pasting is correct, if you wanted the date to be input alongside the new data added that is a little different using the last column formula you've already used.